# Synchronize redux from server side with redux from client

Tags: reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I have written an app in react with server side rendering it works fine, but if I refresh a page in browser I get a checksum error from react, I guess that is because client's redux has a default state after refresh.

Is there a way to keep client's redux state after a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by passing state from server to client and setting it as default state in client.